# Process.Start dirquota.exe - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, system.diagnostics

Banging my head against the wall for around 2 days with this one.

I am using a System.Diagnostics.Process to execute dirquota.exe. I catch an exception at .Start() which is "The system cannot find the file specified".

I am now doing:

```
            foreach (var fi in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\").GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
            }
```

This outputs pretty much every file in that directory apart from dirquota.exe. Anyone?

Cheers.

Comment: are you sure you have dirquota.exe on the machine?

Comment: Yes, positive. I am running it from the command line and I can see it through the Explorer.

Comment: Is it leaving out any other files in the directory? Does this dirquota.exe has any special attributes like hidden/archive etc?

Comment: Hi, yes a couple others I can see missing from the list are Defrag.exe and DeviceEject.exe - there are probably more. The file is not marked as hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running on a 64-bit version of Windows?  Look in c:\windows\syswow64, home of the 32-bit programs.

Comment: Hi I am looking in that folder and there is no dirquota.exe. I can definitely see this file in System32.

Comment: Okay now I have compiled the application to target x64 everything is good. Thank you for the tip that got me thinking!

Comment: @youwhut: be sure to use Any CPU instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this same error and the issue was that the executable program was compiled as x86 and running it in a 64 bit OS.

Changing the project 'Platform Target' to AnyCPU fixes it.